# React components - how to handle different forms of the ui elements e.g. buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find the most performant, and recommended approach to handle different forms of the same semantic components in react e.g. buttons, links.

My dilemma is whether to use base component e.g. Button and then other components like. ButtonIcon that are using that 'base' Button component

VS.

To write the complete logic inside of the button component to make it handle e.g. 'icon' prop and then render this icon component instead of children prop as it would do in the case of non icon button.

Same would apply to e.g. links, where I would have components like link (Next.js routing link), link-external (for a tag external links), link-download, link-as-button etc.

Would I be better off writing one smart component that will e.g. return either next link or a tag depending on props?

I know its more an opinionated question but there has to be a preferred way.

Any advice or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Talking in terms of Buttons : create a base component  that returns a button and accepts different props such as onClick handler, button text, className, type, onMouseDown etc.

```
function Button(props){
    const {title = '', onClick = ''} = props;

    return(
        <button onClick={() => onClick()}>{title}</button>
    )
}
```

Now, use this component where you need it, just keep passing props to it. This, way you'll just the same button and won't need to handle complex logic inside.

Here,  component would be called as Pure Component.
Same goes with Links.